# How to define SQL Server colum name case insensitive but values case sensitive

Tags: sql-server, collation

We just migrated some databases to a new SQL Server 2012 and got some problems with sensitivity.

We would like table & column names to be case insensitive but values should be case sensitive, so

```
select ... where 'a'='A'
```

should not return any row, but

```
select Column from Table
select column from table
```

should both work.

We tried changing the database (server default) from
`Modern_Spanish_CI_AS -> 'a'='A' is true`, which we don't want to be, to
`Modern_Spanish_CS_AS -> the column/table names must match the defined case`

Is there any way to get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose a case-sensitive collation you must ensure that your your queries are case-sensitive because collation applies to metadata as well as user-data .

You can get round the problem by making the database's collation case-insensitive and using the COLLATE clause when creating tables, or alternatively use a contained database.

Read more about [Contained Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929071(v=sql.110).aspx) and [Contained Database Collations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929080(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: Should I understand that the COLLATE clause of a create database applies to metadata as well as user-data ... whereas the COLLATE clause of a column definition in a create table  applies only to user-data?

Comment: Yes. You can avoid having to use the COLLATE clause of a column definition if your database is a contained database - see the link in my answer to Contained Database Collations, and here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929071(v=sql.110).aspx about contained databases.

Comment: Thks. You are right, Tested the COLLATE on a column. We will study which option is easier, collate on each column or contained database.